(Modulo Arithmetic) Modular congruence
I'm working through some challenges on cryptohack.org and am new to modular arithmetic. They describe it in the following terms:

Formally, "calculating time" is described by the theory of
congruences. We say that two integers are congruent modulo m if a ≡ b
mod m.
Another way of saying this, is that when we divide the integer a by m,
the remainder is b. This tells you that if m divides a (this can be
written as m | a) then a ≡ 0 mod m.

The goal here is to write code that calculates the following two values:

11 ≡ x mod 6
8146798528947 ≡ y mod 17

Their definition/explanation is rather brief so I am hoping that someone could expand on this in more simple terms. I've researched online and it's always seemingly over complicated.
Can someone explain what this means in terms that a someone who hasn't done math in quite a while would understand? Additionally, if anyone here has references for books that could be used to learn these concepts in a structured way, that'd be fantastic.
Also, please don't solve the challenge, if you would like to provide an example, use a different set of numbers. Thank you!

Since the question is about writing code, you should pick a programming language. Most languages provide a remainder or modulus operator. If you are asking for a tutorial on modular arithmetic, Stack Overflow just isn't the place for that.

Yeah, I suppose math overflow would be better. I know how to perform modulo, it's pretty basic in all languages. I'm looking more specifically on the actual mathematical explanation of modulo congruence.

MathOverflow is for advanced math. Mathematics is closer to what you want, but there is no Stack site that's right for this question. There are tutorials all over the web on modular arithmetic, and also Modular Arithmetic on Wikipedia.

Yep, that looks like the place I ended up finding
